# Replacing the values of a time series with the values of another time series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames:

```
s1: 
         time     X1
0  1234567000  96.32
1  1234567005  96.01
2  1234567009  96.05

s2: 
         time     X2
0  1234566999  23.88
1  1234567006  23.96
```

I would like to replace the values of the first time series/DataFrame with the second DataFrame while keeping the timestamp, to obtain:

```
frame: 
         time     X2
0  1234567000  23.88
1  1234567005  23.88
2  1234567009  23.96
```

The output (`frame`) should have the timestamps of `s1` but the values of `s2`.
`time` is integer (It isn't a UNIX timestamp). `X1` and `X2` are float.

Is there any neat way to do it with pandas?

---

I currently use a chain of outer join/merge + fillna + inner join/merge + del columns, but that doesn't seem efficient.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pandas as pd

def merge_dataframes(s1, s2, common_column, back_fill=False, verbose=False):
    if verbose: print('s1: \n{0}'.format(s1))
    if verbose: print('s2: \n{0}'.format(s2))
    frame = pd.merge(s1,s2,how='outer').sort_values(by=common_column)
    if verbose: print('frame: \n{0}'.format(frame))
    frame.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
    if verbose: print('frame: \n{0}'.format(frame))
    frame = pd.merge(frame,s1,how='inner').sort_values(by=common_column)
    if verbose: print('frame: \n{0}'.format(frame))        
    for column_name in s1.columns:
        if (column_name not in common_column) and (column_name not in s2.columns):
            del frame[column_name]
    if back_fill:
        frame.fillna(method='bfill', inplace=True)
        if verbose: print('frame: \n{0}'.format(frame))            
    return frame

def main():
    '''
    Demonstrate the use of merge_dataframes(s1, s2, common_column)
    '''
    s1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'time':[1234567000,1234567005,1234567009],
        'X1':[96.32,96.01,96.05]
    },columns=['time','X1'])  

    s2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'time':[1234566999,1234567006],
        'X2':[23.88,23.96]
    },columns=['time','X2'])  

    common_column = 'time'
    frame = merge_dataframes(s1, s2, common_column, verbose=True)
    print('frame: \n{0}'.format(frame))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    #cProfile.run('main()') # if you want to do some profiling
```

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you mean "replace and keep the timestamps"? I can't really see the mapping here.

Comment: @Mitch The output should have the timestamps of s1 but the values of s2. Please let me know if still unclear.

Comment: Ahh I see how the timestamp mapping is intended work - it is effectively timeseries data. Thanks!

Comment: did you [try](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) `pd.merge_asof()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pd.merge_asof` works for me on your sample

```
pd.merge_asof(s1,s2,on='time')
Out[108]: 
         time     X1     X2
0  1234567000  96.32  23.88
1  1234567005  96.01  23.88
2  1234567009  96.05  23.96
```

**Edit - A solution for absolute merging**

```
def Matcher2(value,mat):
    return np.argmin(np.absolute(mat-value))

mat = s2.time.as_matrix()
s1['dex'] = s1.time.apply(lambda row: Matcher2(row,mat))
mg = pd.merge(s1,s2,left_on='dex',right_index=True,how='left')
print mg[['time_x','X1','X2']]

       time_x     X1     X2
0  1234567000  96.32  23.88
1  1234567005  96.01  23.96
2  1234567009  96.05  23.96
```

Comment: That looks perfect, thanks! The [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html)  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170811002311/http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html)) is a bit misleading.  "Perform an asof merge. This is similar to a left-join except that we match on nearest key rather than equal keys." -> it is nearest key in the past. (otherwise  we would have `1  1234567005  96.01  23.96`). Luckily that's what I wanted :-)

Comment: Yes its not an absolute match, which I is unfortunate in a case I had in the past, where I had to apply a function to find the absolute closest time. Lucky for you in this case :)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt add  my solution , in case you need search abs(distance)

Comment: @Wen interesting! I was stuck on that in the past, I added the method I used, however I curious what would be faster. Will have to check at a later time :)

Comment: There is no doubt build in function is faster but it is limit by pre defined logic like "search" in past index

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt  ,After timing test, I updated itertools product method, saving around 1 of 3 rd running time.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution , I break down the step.

1st only search in the past:

```
M1=pd.DataFrame({},index=df1.time,columns=df2.time)
M1=M1.apply(lambda x:x.index-x.name)
del M1.index.name
M2=M1.stack().reset_index()
M2=M2.loc[M2[0]>=0,]
M2[0]=abs(M2[0])
M2=M2.sort_values(['level_0',0]).drop_duplicates(['level_0'],keep='first')
df1.merge(M2,left_on='time',right_on='level_0',how='left').merge(df2,left_on='time_y',right_on='time').loc[:,['time_x','X1','X2']]
       time_x     X1     X2
0  1234567000  96.32  23.88
1  1234567005  96.01  23.88
2  1234567009  96.05  23.96
```

2nd search all: the only different is on `M2=M2.loc[M2[0]>=0,]`

```
M1=pd.DataFrame({},index=df1.time,columns=df2.time)
M1=M1.apply(lambda x:x.index-x.name)
del M1.index.name
M2=M1.stack().reset_index()
#M2=M2.loc[M2[0]>=0,]
M2[0]=abs(M2[0])
M2=M2.sort_values(['level_0',0]).drop_duplicates(['level_0'],keep='first')
df1.merge(M2,left_on='time',right_on='level_0',how='left').merge(df2,left_on='time_y',right_on='time').loc[:,['time_x','X1','X2']]



Out[173]: 
       time_x     X1     X2
0  1234567000  96.32  23.88
1  1234567005  96.01  23.96
2  1234567009  96.05  23.96
```

Updated by using `itertools` `product`

```
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd
DF=pd.DataFrame(list(product(df1.time, df2.time)), columns=['l1', 'l2'])
DF['DIFF']=DF.l1-DF.l2
DF=DF.loc[DF.DIFF>=0,]
DF=DF.sort_values(['l1','DIFF']).drop_duplicates(['l1'],keep='first')
df1.merge(DF,left_on='time',right_on='l1',how='left').merge(df2,left_on='l2',right_on='time').loc[:,['time_x','X1','X2']]


Out[357]: 
       time_x     X1     X2
0  1234567000  96.32  23.88
1  1234567005  96.01  23.88
2  1234567009  96.05  23.96
```