# Pandas join on immediate predecessor

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, merge

I will describe my problem through an example:

```
x = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'row':[5, 10, 12], 'val_x': [11,222, 333]})
y = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'row':[2, 4, 9, 13], 'val_y': [1, 12, 123,  4]})
In [4]: x

   row  val_x
0    5     11
1   10    222
2   12    333

In [5]: y

   row  val_y
0    2      1
1    4     12
2    9    123
3   13      4
```

I want each row in `x` to be joined with a row in `y`, that is immediately before it according to the row column (equal value is also allowed)

In other words, the output looks like

```
   row  val_x   row_y  val_y
0    5     11    4      12
1   10    222    9      123
2   12    333    9      123
```

I know I need some sort of special merge on the row columns, but I have no idea exactly how to express it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html)

```
pd.merge_asof(x,y,on='row',direction ='backward').merge(y,left_on='val_y',right_on='val_y')
Out[828]: 
   row_x  val_x  val_y  row_y
0      5     11     12      4
1     10    222    123      9
2     12    333    123      9
```

EDIT:

```
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd
DF=pd.DataFrame(list(product(x.row, y.row)), columns=['l1', 'l2'])

DF['DIFF']=DF.l1-DF.l2
DF=DF.loc[DF.DIFF>=0,:]
DF=DF.sort_values(['l1','DIFF']).drop_duplicates(['l1'],keep='first')
x.merge(DF,left_on='row',right_on='l1',how='left').merge(y,left_on='l2',right_on='row')[['row_x','val_x','row_y','val_y']]

   row_x  val_x  row_y  val_y
0      5     11      4     12
1     10    222      9    123
2     12    333      9    123
```

Comment: @BaronYugovich update your pandas ..dude..to pandas 0.20.3

Comment: How about if that's not an option for me? Any other way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45625065/replacing-the-values-of-a-time-series-with-the-values-of-another-time-series-in/45625192#comment78212882_45625192, check my answer there

Comment: @BaronYugovich still recommend you update pandas, if you do not want to, look at my updated solution .

Comment: Thanks. I do want to update it, just ran into some trouble